# Azure Logic App invoking Azure Function is failing

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I have an SFTP trigger that send the contents to an Azure Function. When Logic App invokes the Function, in the designer view I observe that it fails after 9 minutes.  When I look at the Function monitor, I observe that the function is still running. The function is C#. I When the function completes, it logs the difference in DateTime between when it starts and ends. The time printed is about 300 seconds or five minutes. I know this is the limit for the time for a function to run.

This function runs in only 30 seconds on a VM on my five year old computer. Why is performance in Azure Function so poor? Is there anything that can be done to make it perform better?

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do in the function?

What is the processing-time of the function if you test it in Function app itself rather than from the Logic App?

Comment: "What are you trying to do in the function?"   --

The function takes a text payload from Logic App which is a TSV file with thousands to tens of thousands of rows. The data gets partitioned by a date column and sent to BigQuery.

"What is the processing-time of the function if you test it in Function app itself rather than from the Logic App?" --

Haven't tried. I'm curious why one would ask/test? Is how a Function get invoked have any affect on how the Function runs?

Comment: Because testing it in your Function App would give you addtional trace information about your function during execution.

Comment: My trace logging says it runs REALLY slow. Is that just the nature of Azure Functions at this time?

Comment: I haven't encountered slow functions so far, but I haven't build cases like yours. Perhaps you could add additional tracing to your function, to help you figure out what part of the code is causing the slow performance?